# what process do you follow while designing a ui for mobile app or website?

Tags: interface-design, sketch-app

how do you start designing a mobile app.
what is your process.

i had lot of confusion and finally it led to be frustrated about my workflow.
i use sketch for designing but before coming to sketch what is the process that you follow.

like getting idea from client-working on a idea-prototype-testing-user research-then wireframe-build-test.

so when i come into sketch what are tips and tricks that a designer should follow to make life easy and make it more productive.

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

- I write the idea down on a paper. Then brainstorm design on paper by making mockups and defining the flow of design. **This gives me some basic or medium level understanding of the product.**
- Secondly I open sketch and design my hand drawn designs with grayscale layout and simple rectangles, squares and circles a digital mockup you can say. While doing this step I also make changes which I didn't though about while doing them on paper.
- Then I clean the mockup. These are still grayscale but in this step I clean them so they start to look a gray scale mobile app or website. This is the step from where I'll start designing.
- Finally i start the design and this si the colorful stuff. Sometimes the color requirement is from client side but sometimes you have to come up with the contrast.

*Love the design and the design will love you :)*